# Why doesn't the Until timeout stop execution of inner activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an Until loop with a single Web activity inside. The Until loop has a 0.00:00:30 second timeout. The Web activity will eventually return a value that satisfies the Until condition, ending the loop. However, the loop exits more than 00:01:00 minutes after the Until loop starts. The pipeline status shows that the Until loop *did* timeout, but never stopped executing. Why isn't this working?[image]

Comment: Additional info: I have discovered a warning in ADF Studio that appears if the Until timeout does not match the expected format: "Timeout is invalid. The value must be formatted as D.HH:MM:SS and be no more than 7 days and no less than 10 minutes". Rakesh ran a test below that timed out in less than 10 minutes, however, so I doubt that this error message represent the actual minimum limit.

Answer (score 0):

I ran until activity with a time out of **2 mins** and the condition is `true`.

[image]

Inside until, I took two wait activities of time **5 mins** and **1 min** respectively. In between that I have used a sample set variable activity.

[image]

I have executed the pipeline, and these are the results.

[image]

You can see that the until activity continued the execution after the wait activity and **it got timed out only after the current iteration**.

To cross check this, and I changed the condition of until to `false` and time out to **2 mins**. I have set the wait activities time limit to **20 seconds** and **60 seconds** respectively.

This time as well, **even though the until activity time out reached in the middle of the current iteration, it got only timed out after that particular iteration**.

[image]

So, based on these results, this is the observation that if until activity time limit reaches in the middle of an iteration, it will time out only after the executing the current iteration.

Comment: Thank you for this analysis. However, I have confirmed externally that my inner Web activity always returns a value in less than a second. Based on your test, I would therefore expect my Until loop to timeout within a fraction of a second after the timeout period. But it does not.